# Weird C# Threading ThreadInterrupted exception

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am developing an application simulating a network comprising a number of nodes that exchange messages. I try to simulate the transmission channel with a Queue where every node can place a message. Then, another entity takes over the message and delivers it to the specified node. Then, i want to signal (with an event) the end of a transmission phase when the message queue is **idle** for a certain amount of time, say X, namely no new messages have been added to the queue for X mseconds.

I understand that my case follows the consumer/producer paradigm. So far, i have done the following:

```
public class Com<T>
{
    private Thread dispatcher;
    private Queue<T> queue;
    private int waitTime;
    private Object locker;
    private Timer timer;
    public event EventHandler EmptyQueueEvent;

    public Com()
    {
        queue = new Queue<T>();
        locker = new Object();
        waitTime = X;
        timer = new Timer(FireEmpty, null, Timeout.Infinite,Timeout.Infinite);
        dispatcher = new Thread(Serve);
        dispatcher.IsBackground = true;
                    dispatcher.Start();
    }

    private void Serve()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                if (queue.Count == 0)
                {
                    timer.Change(waitTime, 0);
                    Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
                }
            }
            catch (ThreadInterruptedException)
            {
            }
            while (queue.Count != 0)
            {
                lock (locker)
                {
                    deliver(queue.Dequeue());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void deliver(T item)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
        lock (locker)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(item);
        }
        dispatcher.Interrupt();
    }

    private void FireEmpty(object o)
    {
        //Fire Event
    }
}
```

However, running my simulations proves that my synchronization is not enough, since I am sometimes getting a "ThreadInterruptedException" while trying to dequeue my message (in method Serve()). Note that the exception does not occur each time i run the simulation, but rather rarely: approximately every 850-1000 executions (i am running the execution iteratively)..

Does anybody have an idea what it is wrong with my code? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried locking before you attempt to get the `Queue` count? Like:

```
    private void Serve()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                int count = 0;
                lock(locker)
                   count= queue.Count;
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    timer.Change(waitTime, 0);
                    Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
                }
            }
            catch (ThreadInterruptedException)
            {
            }
            while (queue.Count != 0)
            {
                lock (locker)
                {
                    deliver(queue.Dequeue());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It's possible that an add is getting called at the same time you're trying to count the number of items.  Also, you might want to consider one of the collections from [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) if you're using .net 4.0.

** **UPDATE** **

I just took a closer look at your code and had an "Oh duh" moment.  You should be getting a `ThreadInterruptException` because you're calling `delegate.Interrupt()`.  Check the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.interrupt.aspx) on that.  I think what you need to do is use something like a [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) and instead of calling `Interrupt()` do a [`WaitOne()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85bbbxt9.aspx) on that event.

** **UPDATE2** **
Here's some sample code that includes my other locking suggestion as well (on Gist):
https://gist.github.com/1683547

Comment: @Coding Gorilla: That did not work either; I got the exact same exception at the exact point :( Thanks for the hint though!

Comment: @Coding Gorilla It would be really nice if you indeed provided an example :) Thanks again!

Comment: @user1171442 Posted a link to a gist for you